# Error when changing PHP version on Heroku app

Tags: laravel, heroku, php-7.2

As some of you might know, PHP version ≥7.2 has an issue regarding count: `count(): parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable` and this does contributes to a lot of problems.

I'm using the PHP framework [Laravel 5.3](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3) on [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com), which until the change of PHP version worked perfectly fine. So why don't I just change the PHP version? Well, according to the docs I'm supposed to just change the version in my `composer.json`, run `composer update` and everything will be fine but no - I'm getting this error:

`Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.`

`Problem 1
    - This package requires php ^5.6.4 but your PHP version (7.2.1) does not satisfy that requirement.`

Anyone knowing anything that can contribute solving my problem?

Comment: The `compose update` is being run in your machine?

Comment: Could you post the whole error (about composer update)?

Comment: This is all I get from composer update

Comment: @EstebanGarcia No, "composer update" is run on heroku environment. More exactly, this is executed - ```heroku run composer update --app myapp```

Answer (score 1):

You also need to push composer.lock.

1. Change the version in your local and make `$ composer update`.
2. Make sure you have changed composer.lock.
3. Push both files on Heroku.

From the documentation, https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#php-runtimes

> Next, ensure that your new requirements are “frozen” to composer.lock
>   by running:

```
$ composer update
```

> Finally, don’t forget to git add and git commit both files!

Hope this helps.